# sed - Incorporate a string from specific file/folder names into text files

Tags: sed

I try to add a string to the first line in text files.

The first part of every string is identical. Here "#Test:". The last part of the string should incorporate the digit which is derived from the folder and file names.
The folder names consist exclusively of digits from 1-52. There are between 1-20 files in each folder with the following structure:

- 1 (folder)

  - 1_tree1 (file)
  - 1_tree2 (file)
  - 1_tree3 (file)

    ...
- 2 (folder)

  - 2_tree1 (file)
  - 2_tree2 (file)
  - 2_tree3 (file)

    ...
- ...

The operating system is Ubuntu 20.04.

I am able to change each file separately. For example, the following command in the terminal adds #Tree:1 for one file the first folder.

```
sed -i '1s/^/#Test:1 \n/' '/path/to/the/file'
```

However, if I try to do this for all files in the folder, I can not proceed. Could you show me how to do it automatically? I am not necessarily restricted to `sed`.

Thank you.

Comment: Please do not edit solution announcements into the question. Accept (i.e. click the "tick" next to it) one of the existing answer, if there are any. You can also create your own answer, and even accept it, if your solution is not yet covered by an existing answer. Compare https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: @RaviSaroch please don't add answers in comments where they can't be up/downvoted by the community. If you have an answer then just add it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be what you want, using GNU awk for "inplace" editing, `BEGINFILE` (so it'll work even on empty input files), and `gensub()`:

```
find . -type f -exec awk -i inplace '
    BEGINFILE { print "#Test:" gensub(".*/([0-9]+)_[^/]+$","\\1",1,FILENAME) }
1' {} +
```